Second cat steals first cat's food
I recently got a new cat (Saffron, about a year old) and she's ...very food-motivated. I'm not sure exactly what her background is but she was underweight when I got her and apparently was bullied by other pets where she was living.
My other cat, Sage (also about a year), likes to graze throughout the day and doesn't have issues with overeating.
I've tried getting them both on a set feeding schedule, morning and evening, but Saffron will inhale her food and go for Sage's as soon as Sage wanders away. Sometimes she'll squeeze her head in the bowl and eat at the same time.
I don't think an RFID feeder would work because Saffron will just stick her head in when it's open. I've been taking Sage's bowl away when she's done and giving it back when she asks, but I'm away during the day and I don't want food to be a source of stress for her.
Because of the layout of my apartment, I can't really isolate them during feedings.
Saffron has gained weight since I got her and is now a healthy weight. On her initial checkup, the vet didn't find anything with the standard tests. I'm going to ask about possible medical causes at a followup appointment soon, but if her food issues stem from past trauma, what can I do to deal with them in the short- and long-term?
